# WindowExitTransition always fades views

Tags: java, android, transition

I am currently trying to make a SharedElementTransition between two Activitys, which works mostyl fine, except one thing.
The ExitAnimation of the first activity consists of two slide transitions:
activity_main_transition.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">

    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom" android:duration="@integer/anim_duration">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/bottom_appbar"/>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/fab"/>
        </targets>
    </slide>

    <slide android:slideEdge="top" android:duration="@integer/anim_duration">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/pager"/>
        </targets>
    </slide>

</transitionSet>
```

But when the Transition plays the views not only slides, but also fades, also the transition tooks roughly a third of the time specified in the duration. I also checked while debugging and the Transitionset which got played is the one i described above. The other three transitions are working just fine, even though i use the same transition file for the enter and exit transition, so i don't have any idea what is causing this behavior.
Also some additional code:

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/activity_main</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/activity_main</item>

    </style>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
...
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activitys.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

How i start the new activity:

```
TextView sharedText = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
String transition = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(sharedText);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.
        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), sharedText, transition);
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityCustomer.class);
i.putExtra("id", item.getId());
i.putExtra("title", item.getName1()+" "+item.getName2());
i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_TRANSITION_NAME, transition);
Transition t =  getActivity().getWindow().getExitTransition();
startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```